# images / pictures don't all display on ipad app made with sencha touch and phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, extjs, image

I just made my first ipad app and it has alot of images. There are about 130 pages of content. To display the content and images, I used cards with the html property ex:

`card{`

> > html:'`content stuff < img src="/local/folder/pic.png" />`'

}

I just added the space between < and the img to make sure it shows up correctly in this post.

For Some reason the first few pages I click on load the images, and the rest of the pages have blank place holders for where the image should be.

I made it with sencha touch and tested it in safari, which it works fine in. All the pictures show up. But once I throw it in phone gap, and test it on an actual device, not all the pictures / images show up.  All the pictures are .png files too, which shouldn't make a difference.

Please help me out! I looked like an idiot when I tried testing the app on my friends ipad and couldn't get it to work like it did on safari.

Comment: update: 

  almost fully works when building for 4.3 ios, just a few certian pictures don't show up. ||

  when building for 4.2 ios about half the pictures don't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I finally fixed it! The pictures I got from the client happened to be HUGE. (about 2mb per) So I re-sized and sacrificed some of the quality to lessen the memory usage. I only did a few at the time because I had about 330 pictures... and wanted to be sure before I ran through all of them. I thought that would fix it, and it should have, but there were still problems with the consistency.

Eventually I found out that when I make a new project, the few changes I made finally showed up. But after a few runs they would stop showing up. Then I finally realized that Xcode is REALLY buggy and you have to clear the build after every time (especially with a large app)
for it to display the changes. Other wise it will run an earlier version of the application that you are building (so frustrating). Now the app works!